# Pusher: JSON returned empty string

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm trying to make real-time notifitcation system in Laravel using Pusher and Laravel-Echo. So in Vue file, when I'm connection to private channel, JSON returned from auth endpoint is empty string.

Here are my codes.

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teacher',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Teacher::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,    
});

Pusher.logToConsole = true;
```

Vue file, connecting to private channel in mounted function

```
mounted(){
        window.Echo.private('homeworknotif')
        .listen('HomeworkAdded', e => {
          console.log(e);
        })
      },
```

**HomeworkAdded event file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HomeworkAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('homeworknotif');
    }
}
```

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('homeworknotif', function($user, $id){
    return true;
});
```

broadcasting in controller

```
public function eventer(){
        broadcast(new HomeworkAdded('hello world'));
    }
```

When I'm changing window.Echo.private to window.Echo.channel, there's no error, logs in console show, that I have sent a data, but data is visible only in logs.

Comment: It sounds as though your client may not be able to subscribe to the private channel. 
Do you see any errors with the subscription, or a successful subscription to the channel in the Debug Console? https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019421133-How-can-I-use-the-Channels-debug-console-and-event-creator-

Comment: @doydoy After each page refresh in Debug Console I see connection.

Comment: Do you see a subscription as well? A connection indicates your client can communicate with Pusher, but it still needs to subscribe to the channel (which will be when the authentication takes place). You should be able to see an Error Log in the dashboard as well, this may help identify the issue.

Comment: @doydoy There's no error. I'll try other methods. Thank you for your comment., now I know little bit more about pusher :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't belive, but I didn't set my BROADCAST_DRIVER in .env file, it was log not pusher.